# Computing Graph Metrics in Neo4j/Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a very large graph database in Neo4j, and I'm looking to compute the graph metrics for each node (centrality, etc.) and then export it to my statistical software for further analysis. Is there a way to compute these graph metrics for each node and have them added as properties of the node either as a Cypher query or otherwise within Neo4j?

I've tried using Gephi (and ran out of memory), and it's too large to export to NodeXL, which was the only other solution I saw while searching.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into maybe using something like Gremlin (perhaps via bulb in Python) and then solving computationally?

Comment: @zach-sheffler How did this end ?

Comment: @rzo Probably not the ideal solution, but I wrote a Python script and computed the metrics using the NetworkX package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I guess, I will have similar issues but community is developing some promising plugins :)

Answer (score 0):

You surely can do what ever you want with using Cypher. For example the following simple code will write the centrality degree of each node into its corresponding property.

```
MACH p=(n)-[]-()
SET n.centralityDegree=count(p)
```

But I recommend to take a look at the following links as same features are implemented:

https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#centrality